# Getting "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call" error

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and trying to write my first few codes. One of them is "Create a method that takes 'n' Numpy arrays of same dimensions sums them and return the answer."

```
  def sumarr(n,a,b):
      sum = np.zeros((a,b))
      for i in range(1, n+1):
        arr(i) = np.random.randint(10, size(a,b))
        print(arr(i))
        sum = sum + arr(i)
    
      return sum
    
    
    n= int(input("Enter no. of arrays you wish to take: "))
    a = int(input("Enter no. of rows here: "))
    b = int(input("Enter no. of columns here: "))
    
    
    sumarr(n,a,b)
```

I'm getting "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call" error, not sure why. Can someone please look into this code and point me to the issue and explain while correcting the code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. pls always post the error

Answer (score 2):

Replace `arr(i)` with `arr[i]`.

Also, `sum` is a python keyword. Use a better variable name to store your results.

Comment: Replacing arr(i) with arr[i] throws another error:
'function' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Can you put your new code (and error traceback) in comments?

Comment: I guess I found what the issue was with my code:

 1. I cannot use anything as a variable name...when I was putting arr(i) it was believing itself to be a function which it was not. Hence, replacing arr(i) with arr_i worked. 

 2. And ofcourse, like Ketan mentioned sum is a reserved keyword in Python so better not to use as a variable name.

Comment: Here's what my corrected code looks like:


    def sumarr(n,a,b):
      s = np.zeros((a,b))
      for i in range(1, n+1):
        arr_i = np.random.randint(10, size=(a,b))
        print(arr_i)
        s = s + arr_i
    
      return s
    
    
    n= int(input("Enter no. of arrays you wish to take: "))
    a = int(input("Enter no. of rows here: "))
    b = int(input("Enter no. of columns here: "))
    
    
    sumarr(n,a,b)